# Convert a byte to a number C#

Tags: c#

How can I convert a byte to a number in C#?  For example, 00000001 to 1, 00000011 to 3, 00001011 to 11.  i have a byte array with numbers encoded as binary bytes, but I need to get those numbers and append them to a string.

Comment: Could you please show an example of the byte array and the string that you would like to get? For example, `byte[] data = new byte[] {<show your data here>};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this.

```
// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first),
// reverse the byte array.
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
   Array.Reverse(bytes);
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

where bytes is your bytes[]. You would want to take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx)

Comment: That is not very likely to be what he  wants.

Answer (score 2):

In C# `byte` is already an unsigned number ranging from `0` to `255`. You can freely assign them to integers, or convert to other numeric types.

Comment: @EhsanUllah Then OP needs a loop. I wish he provided an example of his data, because "byte array with numbers encoded as binary bytes" is way too broad to provide an exact answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bytes *are* numbers.

If you want to get the numeric value of a single `byte`, just call `ToString()`.

If you have an array of bytes that are part of a little-endian single number, you can use the `BitConverter` class to convert them to a 16, 32, or 64 bit signed or unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use built-in Convert

```
foreach (byte b in array) {
    long dec = Convert.ToInt64(b,2);
}
```